# Moving slow sub-query to With clause

Tags: postgresql, subquery, performance, postgresql-performance

I am trying to optimize this query :

```
SELECT sum(a-alias.s_count) AS count 
FROM a-table a-alias 
WHERE
(
    a-alias.created_at_minute_id >= 
    (floor(extract(epoch from(
        select select_to_time 
        from a_run_table 
        where timeunit = 'hour'
        and status = 'done'
        order by select_to_time desc limit 1)) / 60))
AND(a-alias.s_id = 'some-uuid-number'));
```

This gives me the sum of *s_count* and the result is a number like `29087`. This query takes 60 milliseconds.

I found that if I replace:

```
(floor(extract(epoch from(
    select select_to_time 
    from a_run_table 
    where timeunit = 'hour'
    and status = 'done'
    order by select_to_time desc limit 1)) / 60))
```

...with some constant number like say 246589, the query time reduces to 1.2 milliseconds.

I moved this part to the `With` clause, but I am not able to make it work:

```
WITH last_run AS 
(
    SELECT (floor(extract(epoch from(
        select select_to_time 
        from a_run_table 
        where timeunit = 'hour'
        and status = 'done'
        order by select_to_time desc limit 1)) / 60)) as 'time'
)
SELECT sum(a-alias.s_count) AS count 
FROM a-table a-alias 
WHERE (a-alias.created_at_minute_id >= (select time from last_run)      
AND(a-alias.s_id = 'some-uuid-number'));
```

I am not able to get value from *last_run* using `(select time from last_run)`.

I expect a number from the `sum` function. From `floor` query, I want to get a number which would be used for `>=` in `Where` clause.

#### Other information

Running query gives :

```
WITH last_run AS (SELECT (floor(extract(epoch from(select select_to_time
from a_run_table where timeunit = 'hour' and status = 'done' 
order by select_to_time desc limit 1)) / 60)) as time) select time from last_run;
```

Time:

```
+-------------+
|        time |
|-------------|
| 2.42925e+07 |
+-------------+
```

Also:

```
pgcli --version
Version: 0.20.1
```

Structure of *a_run_table* :

```
| id               | uuid                        |  not null   |
| status           | character varying(50)       |  not null   |
| select_to_time   | timestamp without time zone |  not null   |
| timeunit         | character varying(20)
```

How should I write my query so that I can take value dynamically from outer-query and send it to inner query?

Comment: A question about performance cannot exist without basic information like Postgres version, table definition and a simple description of what your query should achieve. Please consider instructions in the postgresql-performance tag I added.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I am not asking about performance but how to rewrite the query with `with` clause. It is a syntax quetion.

Comment: @AshishNegi: Seems to me like there is *a lot* about performance. Be that as it may, we need the basic information I mentioned either way. And we shouldn't have to ask for it. It should be in your question to begin with.

Comment: sorry for late reply.. i have updated with new details.

Comment: Please add the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output of the slow query.  Without it it is really like asking people to check their crystal balls.  Mine is broken, for one.